# How to extract a text from the screen using SIKULI?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, sikuli

I am using Sikuli to automate a mainframe screen, I need to copy a text on screen and use that as input to another screen.

I cannot find any option on the SIKULI IDE to do the copy function.

My question is, is it possible at all to copy text ?

Answer (score 4):

Sikuli can extract text with OCR (optical character recognition) as described on this page: http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.text

> Extracting Text from a Region class Region text() Extract the text
>   contained in the region using OCR.
>
> Returns:  the text as a string. Multiple lines of text are separated by
>   intervening ‘n’. Note: Since this feature is still in an experimental
>   state, be aware, that in some cases it might not work as expected.

You might need to enable it first like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966942/ocr-in-sikuli-java

There is also an alternative: https://github.com/sarxos/sikuli-ocr